# How to set label to empty string in dropdown?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, multi-select

I'm working on this simple **multiselect dropdown** and I want to set the label to nothing **(empty string)**. However, when I use **defaultLabel** it doesn't seem to work properly. Is there any way to set the label (testing) to an empty string by default?.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's my code:

```
<p-multiselect
    [options]="registrationStatus"
    [defaultLabel]= "someText"
    [showHeader]="false">
</p-multiSelect>
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-input-multiselect-v9zmtf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: It appears to work with unbreakable spaces: `someText: string = "        "`. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-input-multiselect-xczeaj).

Comment: @ConnorsFan even though it works it doesn't seem to be a good solution I don't think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the empty string as the `defaultLabel` and define a global css class that will override the default styles of the control and set the initial size. Also you can set a min-width in the style if you want to start with a specific width. Then you apply your css class using the styleClass property. It is mentioned in the official documentation [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect).

This are the styles to put in in the global css of the application:

```
.multipleSelectSize {
  height: 30px;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.multipleSelectSize > .ui-multiselect-label-container > .ui-multiselect-label {
  height: 27px;
}
```

And the html template where you apply the style:

```
<p-multiSelect [styleClass]="'multipleSelectSize'" [options]="registrationStatus" [defaultLabel]= "someText" [showHeader]="false"></p-multiSelect>
```

Here is also a [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-input-multiselect-xwrexm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: your is not working as expected. You're just trying to add a height that when you mouse over the multiselect dropdown you end up seeing a gray background.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a solution that removes the gray area. It is now a bit more complicated. If you are not ok with this you will have to ask the creators of the components how to do it in a more simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a relatively straightforward workaround: Set the default label to a string of the desired length, say "Default". Then use the [style] attribute provided on the MultiSelectComponent to conditionally apply `color: transparent` whenever there are no selected items. This way, you don't have to deal with setting the height or width appropriately.

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="registrationStatus" [defaultLabel]="someText"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" [showHeader]="false"
    [style]="getDefaultLabelStyle()">
</p-multiSelect>

someText: string = 'Default';
selectedItems: Array<Object> = [ ];

getDefaultLabelStyle() {
    return (this.selectedItems.length === 0) ?
        { color: 'transparent' } : null;
}
```

Full StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-input-multiselect-w7sq4t).